# Setting name of output files

Tags: vba, excel, save, filenames

I currently use a VBA macro that copies and saves all worksheets in a workbook as .csv. The macro that's shown below simply uses the worksheet name as the new file name.

```
Sub ExportSheetsToCSV()
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    Dim xcsvFile As String
    For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        xWs.Copy
        xcsvFile = CurDir & "\" & xWs.Name & ".csv"
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xcsvFile, _
        FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Next
End Sub
```

My question is, how would I go about adding only a portion of the workbooks name to the beginning? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by a portion?

Answer (score 0):

For example (untested)

```
Sub ExportSheetsToCSV()
    Dim xWs As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, wbCopy As Workbook
    Dim xcsvFile As String

    Set wb = Application.ActiveWorkbook

    For Each xWs In wb.Worksheets

        xWs.Copy
        Set wbCopy = Application.ActiveWorkbook
        'include the first 4 characters from the workbook name
        xcsvFile = CurDir & "\" & Left(wb.Name, 4) & "_" & xWs.Name & ".csv"
        wbCopy.SaveAs Filename:=xcsvFile, FileFormat:=xlCSV, _
                      CreateBackup:=False

        wbCopy.Close False 'no save...
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, something like this would work. I'll have to test it but I just simply needed to add the first 10 characters from the original workbook to the beginning of the new csv files.